# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table

I have use **ng2-smart-table** with datepicker.
it returns `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`. use `component: DatepickerComponent`

```
 import { DatepickerComponent } from '../forms/datepicker/datepicker.component';
    export class LicenceDeviceComponent implements OnInit {
      settings = {
        columns: {
          licence_expiry_date: {
            title: 'Licence Expiry Date',
            type: 'string',
            editor: {
              type: 'custom',
              component: DatepickerComponent,
            },
            filter: {
              type: 'custom',
              component: DatepickerComponent,
            },
          },
        },
      };
    }
```

This my **Datepicker** component `forms/datepicker/datepicker.component`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NbDateService } from '@nebular/theme';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-datepicker',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker.component.scss'],
})

export class DatepickerComponent {
  constructor(protected dateService: NbDateService<Date>) {}
}
```

`forms/datepicker/datepicker.component.html`

```
<input nbInput placeholder="Select Expiry Date" [nbDatepicker]="formpicker" id="expiry_date" #licence_expiry_date>
<nb-datepicker #formpicker format="yyyy-MM-dd"></nb-datepicker>
```